# How to appends new data items to my GridView adapter

Tags: android, gridview, pagination, adapter, android-gridview

I have a GridView display images. I create a setOnScrollListener to check when the user get to the bottom of he gridview. 
Then I need to append new images to the gridview. (just like the endless adpter).

But I can not find an way to update my adpter. Can you give me a hand please. Many thanks:

this is the method i am working on :

```
public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) { ...... SEE BELOW ...... }
```

**GridView Activity**

```
//This Activity Loads the Get Images Thumnail in a GridView
public class GalleryInGridViewCallfromAPI extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = GalleryInGridViewCallfromAPI.class.getSimpleName();


    //View v;
        GridView gridview;
        AlbumPhotosAdapter adapter;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        String album_id;    
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        RelativeLayout overlay;
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); //Big Image
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(); //Title of big image
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList_thumb = new ArrayList<String>(); //ThumbNail
        //VarController vc;
        APICall api;

    //Global Json obj for GetBigImageUrl();
        public static JSONObject mJsonobject; //GetBigImageUrl
        public static JSONArray mJsonarray; //GetBigImageUrl

    //Get Data From Home Activity
        Intent intent;
        Bundle bundle;
        String mGetAlbumCategory;

    //Global to set new paginated data
        //Page Number
        public static int mPageNumberInt = 1;
        public static String mPageNumber = Integer.toString(mPageNumberInt);
        //Items Limit
        public static int mItemLimitInt = 30;
        public static String mItemLimit = Integer.toString(mItemLimitInt);




        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.album_photo_list);


            intent = this.getIntent();
            bundle = intent.getExtras();
            mGetAlbumCategory = bundle.getString("category");



        //vc = new VarController(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        api = new APICall(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);


        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter = new AlbumPhotosAdapter());


        // ONSCROLLLISTENER
        // Attach the listener to the AdapterView onCreate
        gridview.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
            customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
                // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EndlessScrollListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });



     // ONCLICK
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Log.w("view pager", "111: " + position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "setOnItemClickListener" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //startImagePagerActivity(position);
                String[] mImages = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[stringArrayList.size()]);
                String[] mImagesTiles = stringArrayListTitle.toArray(new String[stringArrayListTitle.size()]);
                String[] mThumbImages = stringArrayList_thumb.toArray(new String[stringArrayList_thumb.size()]);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putStringArray("photo_list", mImages);
                    bundle.putStringArray("url_title", mImagesTiles);
                    bundle.putStringArray("thumb_list", mThumbImages);
                    bundle.putInt("pos", position);

                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                //intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ImageGallery_ViewPager_from_GambaPanas.class);//trying out
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ImageGallery.class);//works without Panigation
                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });


        return ;
    }


        // Append more data into the adapter
        public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {
          // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
          // Use the offset value and add it as a parameter to your API request to retrieve paginated data.
          // Deserialize API response and then construct new objects to append to the adapter
            mPageNumberInt = 2;
            //Call get new date
            //gridview.setAdapter(adapter = new AlbumPhotosAdapter());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }





//New Adapter
    public class AlbumPhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        List<AlbumPhotosDataStruct> list = new ArrayList<AlbumPhotosDataStruct>();

        public AlbumPhotosAdapter() {

            /** call server retrieve photos by album id **/ 
            GetBigImageUrl();
            getPhotosList();

            Collections.reverse(list);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public AlbumPhotosDataStruct getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo_grid_item, parent, false);
            } else {
                v = (View) convertView;
            }




            AlbumPhotosDataStruct z = getItem(position);            
            String thumb_url = z.thumb_url;

            ImageView imgView =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgView, true);

            return v;
        }

        protected void getPhotosList(){

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
                    if (isCancelled())
                        return "";

                    String result = "";

                    APICall api = new APICall(MyApplication.getAppContext());

                    Log.i("getPhotosList *******************", "mPageNumber : " + mPageNumber);

                    api.setAPIurl(getString(R.string.api_url));
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", "getlist"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", mGetAlbumCategory));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", mPageNumber));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", mItemLimit));

                    result = api.getAPIContents(nameValuePairs);

                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    //Log.d("toppaidTest","processing2");

                    if (!result.equals("")) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                            String status = jObject.getString("status");

                            if (status.equals("success")) {
                                // Log.e("status",status);

                                JSONArray jArray_data = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("data"));

                                //loop album Thumb
                                if(jArray_data.length() > 0){
                                     for (int i = 0; i<jArray_data.length(); i++) {

                                        //String thumb_url = jArray_data.getJSONObject(i).getString("link").toString();

                                        String thumb_url = jArray_data.getString(i);

                                            Log.v("Loop thumb_url", "thumb_url: " + thumb_url);

                                        AlbumPhotosDataStruct newData = new AlbumPhotosDataStruct(thumb_url);
                                        list.add(newData);

                                        //stringArrayList.add(thumb_url); //add to arraylist
                                        stringArrayList_thumb.add(thumb_url);                                                                       
                                     }

                                     Log.i("After loop - stringArrayList_thumb", "stringArrayList_thumb: " + stringArrayList_thumb);
                                 }

                            }
                            else{
                                //show default album
                                showDefaultPhoto();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            //show default album
                            showDefaultPhoto();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        //show default album
                        showDefaultPhoto();
                    }

                    //dialog.dismiss();

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }.execute();
        }
//---- Get Actual Image ******************************************************************************************
        protected void GetBigImageUrl(){

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
                    if (isCancelled())
                        return "";

                    String result = "";

                    APICall api = new APICall(MyApplication.getAppContext());

                    api.setAPIurl(getString(R.string.api_url));
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", "getimages"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", mGetAlbumCategory));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", mPageNumber));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", mItemLimit));

                    result = api.getAPIContents(nameValuePairs);

                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    //Log.d("toppaidTest","processing2");

                    if (!result.equals("")) {

                        try {

                            mJsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
                            String status = mJsonobject.getString("status");

                            if (status.equals("success")) {
                                // Log.e("status",status);

                                mJsonarray = new JSONArray(mJsonobject.getString("data"));

                                //loop API 2 Full Image
                                if(mJsonarray.length() > 0){
                                    for (int i = 0; i<mJsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                        String url_title = mJsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title").toString();
                                        String actual_url = mJsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("link").toString();


                                        //AlbumPhotosDataStruct newData = new AlbumPhotosDataStruct(url_title, actual_url);
                                        //list.add(newData);

                                       stringArrayListTitle.add(url_title); //add to arraylistTitle
                                       stringArrayList.add(actual_url); //add to arraylist
                                     }
                                    Log.v("After loop - stringArrayList", "stringArrayList: " + stringArrayList);
                                    Log.v("After loop - stringArrayListTitle", "stringArrayListTitle: " + stringArrayListTitle);
                                 }

                            }
                            else{
                                //show default album
                                //showDefaultPhoto();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //show default album
                            //showDefaultPhoto();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        //show default album
                        //showDefaultPhoto();
                    }

                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }.execute();
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------end get actual image


        private void showDefaultPhoto(){
            Log.e("showDefaultPhoto", "show default photo");
        }



        public class AlbumPhotosDataStruct {
            public String thumb_url;

            public AlbumPhotosDataStruct(String thumb_url) {
                    this.thumb_url = thumb_url;                  
            }
        }

    }
//end new adaptor

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
            Log.e("onPause","leavenow: " + adapter.getCount());
    }


  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
        // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
        // before loading more.
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        // The current offset index of data you have loaded
        private int currentPage = 0;
        // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
        private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        private boolean loading = true;
        // Sets the starting page index
        private int startingPageIndex = 0;

        public EndlessScrollListener() {
        }

        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        }

        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
            this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
            this.currentPage = startPage;
        }

        // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
        // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
        // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) 
            {
            // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
            // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
            if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
                this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
                this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
            }

            // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
            // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
            // number and total item count.
            if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }

            // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
            // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
            // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
                loading = true;
            }
        }

        // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
        public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // Don't take any action on changed
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



}//------body
```

Comment: i guess lazyloading will work for same senario

Comment: have you tried collection.add() to add images and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() also you can add directly to adapter and notify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your customLoadMoreDataFromApi() method you have said that "probably sends out a network request and appends new data items" so it should be done asynchronously. So you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after async task completed. Verify it, and don't re initialize your adapter just add items to your list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). As well as keep your image list (List list ) as a global variable of "GalleryInGridViewCallfromAPI" class. and pass its reference to "AlbumPhotosAdapter" class as constructer argument, otherwise no point in calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

I mean something like below

```
public class GalleryInGridViewCallfromAPI extends Activity {
List<AlbumPhotosDataStruct> list;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    list = new ArrayList<AlbumPhotosDataStruct>();
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter = new AlbumPhotosAdapter());
}

public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {
    mPageNumberInt = 2;
    /*in here call async task and get image from server as list and update global list like below*/
    /*and following should be in asyn task completed function*/
    list.addAll(retrivedNewList);
    /*and then call notifyDataSetChanged*/
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
...
public class AlbumPhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<AlbumPhotosDataStruct> imageList;
    public AlbumPhotosAdapter(List<AlbumPhotosDataStruct> imageList) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
        /** use this locale image list i.e imageList withing this adapter **/ 
        GetBigImageUrl();
        getPhotosList();
        Collections.reverse(imageList);
    }
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Nishan for ur msn. I have a question.
 After I call my new function to get new data from the  async task . How can I update the >list = new ArrayList<AlbumPhotosDataStruct>();< . if it was already initiate at the AlbumPhotosAdapter. Thanks Again